# Use arbitrary colors in Vim and terminator

Tags: vim, terminal, color-scheme, gnome-terminal, terminator

I am working on terminal Vim colorscheme (for 256-color terminal) and I need a few dark colours that I could use as backgrounds. I'm not satisfied with ones available in standard palette - for example, color 22 (`#005f00`), the darkest shade of green, is still too bright.

I've read that terminal Vim does not allow specifying colors as RGB, so - to get arbitrary colors - I would have to tweak terminal emulator's color palette. Is there a way to tweak full 256-color palette in gnome-terminal / terminator? Preferences window only allows editing basic 16.

BTW, Chrome's hterm allows this via 'color-palette-overrides' preference (but has its own drawbacks).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gnome-terminal doesn't offer a UI to alter the colors (apart from the first 16), but you can use escape sequences, e.g.:

`echo -ne '\e]4;22;#004f00\a'`

As you've mentioned, sometimes these colors get reset to their default values. This was a bug in the underlying VTE library, and got fixed in version 0.36.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you won't find a single terminal emulator that gives you that kind of control over the whole *standardized* xterm palette.

So, if you ever intend to share that colorscheme you are stuck with the default palette.

On the other hand, if that colorscheme is only meant for your usage or if you are OK with forcing a hard dependency on your users, you can use [japh's colorcoke](https://github.com/trapd00r/colorcoke) to generate an alternate palette more suited to your needs. See the repo's [wiki](https://github.com/trapd00r/colorcoke/wiki) for examples)

Comment: That's interesting. Under the hood, colorcoke emits escape sequences that change terminal color settings. I thought I could just copy these sequences to my .bashrc. However, on some events (like pressing Alt) colors are reset to default. No idea why it happens.